# Run php file through jquery link click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, get

I cannot get this to work, the page already has other jquery functions running completely fine so i know jquery is working (jplayer and lazyload work fine)

here is my javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function upone() {
    $.get("upone.php");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Here is my link

```
<a href="#" onclick="upone();">Like</a>
```

and my php file "upone.php is :

```
<?php
include("include/config.php");
include("include/functions/import.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['USERID'])&&$_SESSION['USERID']>=0&&is_numeric($_SESSION['USERID']))
{
    $USERID=$_SESSION['USERID'];

    $query="INSERT INTO audio_like SET USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($USERID)."'";
    $result=$conn->execute($query);
}

?>
```

the php file runs fine if i manually link to it, clicking on the link also results in the page refreshing with the # added to the page.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see in firebug or your JavaScript console?

Comment: The only thing i see in the javascript console is a constant error caused by the google+ button, but removing this doesnt change anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using inline javascript, try doing something like this.

Give the "Like" link a class, example:

```
<a href='#' class='likeLink'>Like</a>
```

An instead of your current  section, use something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.likeLink').click(function() {
            $.get('upone.php', function(data) {
                alert("Server Returned: " + data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

If the alert message returns what you expect from the PHP page, you can just comment it out for production.

By the way, I typed this out a long time ago today and forgot I was working on it.  Sorry if it's already solved.

Comment: Thank worked! thank you. Can i ask why this works, while the other way does not?

Comment: The first thing I want to point out is that you should do your best to keep markup, styling and scripting separate from eachother.  Usually in separate files, like a CSS file for styling,  JS file for javascript and an HTML, etc file for markup and including the other files in the head tag.  This is just best practice.  Now for why it works, with jQuery, you should have everything that is tied.

Comment: to an event (like click) inside of the onReady function ( $(function() { ... } ) which I put at the top of the script tag in my example.  This means that it will wait for the DOM to load, then run the scripts inside the braces, so the anchor tag is available before it tries to see it.... My phone is dying I will post more tomorrow.

Comment: Another thing I changed was pulling out that onClick attribute from the anchor tag because jQuery can do that for you using a class or an id attribute.  I went with a class attribute because of the nature of the link - I would assume that you would have multiple like links, if you only had one, you could use the id instead.  Then inside of the onReady function, you need to bind the click event to that anchor tag ( http://api.jquery.com/click/ ), this way when it is clicked, something happens in javascript.

Comment: Then I used a function to execute when the link is clicked which contains the get AJAX request.  Which as you already know, calls the file you put in for the first parameter and returns the result of that page to the data variable which I simply put in an alert call for testing.

Answer (score 6):

*EDIT: Misunderstood the question*

Using the code below will get rid of the issue where the page refreshes after you click the link. The reason it was happening previously is that the `onclick` attribute wasn't returning false, in other words this would have been the right code: `<a href="#" onclick="return upone();">Like</a>`. The code below does the same thing, but structured a little better.

HTML:

```
<a id="like" href="#" >Like</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#like").click(function(){
   $.get("upone.php");
   return false;
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about displaying a result. The PHP  script looks to be something similar to a Stack Exchange upvote, which performs an action server-side without returning anything to the browser...

Comment: Its actually just intended to run a background script for an upvote, but even then, this code isnt working either for whatever reason. :s EDIT: the above comment is correct

Comment: in Firebug or javascript console, do you see the ajax request in the console after you click the link? If so, what's the error that occurs? Most likely, the path from the page to the file is not "upone.php" but something like "/upone.php" or "/scripts/upone.php"

Comment: im not seeing anything after i click the link.  If i click the facebook like or g+ button however, i see them run.

Comment: If you don't see it, check the "Network" tab, it should contain an AJAX request to "upone.php"

Comment: Okay did that, nothing appearing in the Network tab as well unfortunately.